# MongoDb Aggregation reduce returning incorrect result

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

The input to a projection stage of my aggregation is an array like this

```
[ { data: [{Stage: 'A', Amount: 1000}, {}, {}] }, { data... } ]
```

During the projection I am trying to reduce all data of Stage A to the sum of their amounts

```
{
  stageA: {      
    $reduce: {
      input: { 
        $filter: {
          input: "$data",
          as: "item",
          cond: { $eq: [ "$$item.Stage", "A"]}
        }
      },
    initialValue: NumberInt(0),
    in: { $add : ["$$value", "$$this.Amount"] }
  }
}
```

I expect the stageA field to equal 1000 but i get 0 for all data objects, where am I wrong in the expression?

Comment: Working https://mongoplayground.net/p/l0pydNPZA3u

Comment: Thanks for trying this, didn't even know this site existed. Well i pasted some of my code, still cannot get it to work, may you please have a look at this? https://mongoplayground.net/p/-e3CByAbMH1

Comment: A very strange probleme : on playground, copy/paste 'Amount' from configuration to query, it will work! Probably an encoding issue when you copy/paste your code in playground (is A a special greek letter on your keyboard??)

Comment: https://mongoplayground.net/p/uvPGBnQpDUF Problem is with the "Amount" key. Not sure what is the exact issue here. But when I made it in lowercase it does work.

Comment: thank you both, i retyped "Amount" and now it works

Comment: Please type an answer so i can accept it